# Style Highcharts Angular Bullet Graph to look like the Highcharts Bullet Graph

Tags: angular, angular-highcharts

How can I style the bullet graph here https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p2zwf6e8/

```
 chartOptions: Options = {
    series: [
      {
        type: "bullet",
        data: [
          {
            y: 360,
            target: 300
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        type: "bullet",
        data: [
          {
            y: 280,
            target: 250,
            color: "#c0ffee"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        type: "bullet",
        data: [
          {
            y: 150,
            target: 250,
            color: "#bada55"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: "<b>{point.y}</b> (with target at {point.target})"
    }
  };
```

to look like the bullet graph here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/bullet-chart

Comment: Not really clear what is the result you want. You have 3 series with 3 different colors and you set the colors, you removed the yaxis plot bands that adds the design like in the example. You basically changed it to be different. Also there is the link and the code which are different

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.